# jQuery Cross-Domain Call

Tags: jquery, python, cross-domain

I am trying to make crossdomain calls using jQuery, but so far pretty unsuccessful.  My HTML file is on my 'C:/Temp' folder name 'test.html'.  My HTML code is below --

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<input id="first_name" type="text" value="khan" />
<input id="clickme" type="button" value="Click Me!"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickme").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8008/qm/profile/' + $("#first_name").val() + "/",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain : true,
                success: function(response)
                    {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                error: function()
                    {
                        alert("fail");
                    },
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now on the server side I have a little python code that looks like this --

```
def profile(request, username):
    fullname = ''
    if username == 'khan':
        fullname = 'Khan Hannan'
    data = {'fullname': fullname}
    print data
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

The python code is inside DJango project.  If I make a straight call to the URL ('http://localhost:8008/qm/profile/khan'), I get a JSON response back from my server, but when I put the same URL through jQuery, I don't get any response and it fails.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are returning JSONP. Also, i suggest you not work from the filesystem, it has different security rules than a normal webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP works by wrapping your JSON in a function and then executing the function to get the code object.

This is done by sending a callback querystring value to the server which it is then suppose to wrap the JSON object with.

If you inspect the request going out to your server you should see a value being send along called `callback=jquery[long number]`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Thanks Travis.  I was missing the wrapping around the JSON data from my server to client.  That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JSONP callback construct, where the JSON return value is passed to a callback function named in the `callback` request paramater.

The Django Snippets site has a [handy decorator for JSONP](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2208/) that takes care of this for you, and verifies that the user is authenticated as well.

If you don't want to use that decorator, at the very least use the `callback` request parameter in your response, and set the correct content type:

```
return HttpResponse("%s(%s)" % (request.GET['callback'], json.dumps(data)),
    content_type='application/javascript'))
```